# Create empty table with specific height and redraw on button click in SWT

Tags: java, swt, redraw

I want to create an empty SWT table with 2-3 empty rows. Also I want to fill this table with data upon button clicking.

From what I found on the web, it is not possible to create a table with empty rows. If I want empty rows, I would need to add some dummy data which I don't want to (a specific hight of 2-3 rows is good was well). **Is there any other way?**

Preferably I would have a table with header + 3 rows height which keeps that height and adds scrollbars as necessarily. How can I achieve this?

---

My layout for the table is set up like this:

```
Group tableGroup = new Group(parent, SWT.SHADOW_OUT);
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(1, false);
gridLayout.marginWidth = 5;
gridLayout.marginHeight = 5;
tableGroup.setLayout(gridLayout);
tableGroup.setText("Test");

Composite tableComp = new Composite(tableGroup, SWT.NONE);

TableViewerBuilder tableViewerBuilder = new TableViewerBuilder(tableComp, SWT.BORDER | SWT.NO_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);

tableViewer = tableViewerBuilder.getTableViewer();

GridData gridData = new GridData();
gridData.heightHint = tableViewer.getTable().getHeaderHeight()
        + (5 * tableViewer.getTable().getItemHeight());

tableGroup.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

---

Note: `TableViewerBuilder` just creates a new `TableViewer` and sets `TableColumnLayout` to `table.getParent()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size and location of widgets in SWT is controlled by layout managers. Therefore, you need to instruct the layout manager of the table to give it the desired height.

If the parent of the table uses a `GridLayout`, you can use *hints* to influence the size computation of the layout manager.

```java
parent.setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, false ) );
...
Table table = new Table( parent, SWT.NONE );
GridData gridData = new GridData();
gridData.heightHint = table.getHeaderHeight() + ( 3 * table.getItemHeight() );
table.setLayoutData( gridData );
```

The above example tells the grid layout to reserve a height of 3 times the item height, plus room for the header row, for the table.

Note that the `getItemHeight()` may change after you add items, in which case you would need to adjust the height hint and re-layout.

Comment: I could use your code to expand the size of the `Group`, but the table wont grab the excessice space

Comment: You may need to create the GridData with `new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true )` if you want the table to use excess space. See also here for a general introduction to SWT layouts: https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did help me much to achieve the result. Yet here I provide the final solution which worked for me:

```
Group tableGroup = new Group(parent, SWT.SHADOW_OUT);
FillLayout fillLayout = new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL);
fillLayout.marginWidth = 5;
fillLayout.marginHeight = 5;
tableGroup.setLayout(fillLayout);

data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL | GridData.FILL_VERTICAL);

tableGroup.setText("Test");

Composite tableComp = new Composite(tableGroup, SWT.NONE);

TableViewerBuilder tableViewerBuilder = new TableViewerBuilder(tableComp,
        SWT.BORDER | SWT.NO_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

tableViewer = tableViewerBuilder.getTableViewer();
tableViewer.setContentProvider(OpenFigiResponseContentProvider.getInstance());

data.heightHint = tableViewer.getTable().getHeaderHeight()
        + (5 * tableViewer.getTable().getItemHeight());
tableGroup.setLayoutData(data);
tableViewer.getTable().setLayoutData(data);
```

I get a table which completely fill the `Group`